# Google Chrome CSS3 Zoom Transition

Tags: css, google-chrome, transform, transition

I'm working on a website that uses transformations and transitions. The problem is that if I zoom in/out the divs with transitions will get moved slowly instead of getting moved instant(just in Chrome and Opera). Is there an easy fix to it or is it just a problem with Chrome/Opera?

Here the CSS code that I use(just copy it in a div tag):

```
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: can you paste the css for the divs?

Comment: Done. It's quite simple code

Comment: can you put your code in http://fiddle.net , so we can see what problem your facing. Coz that transition code is ok, and maybe you can use a custom `cubic-bezier`.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: On this side there is this problem too. The very first example takes a bit of time to transform if you zoom in/out in Chrome